# How can I get notification when my laptop battery gets fully charged?

Tags: software-recommendation, battery

Sometimes my charger remains plugged into laptop even after charging is complete.

Is there a way to get a pop-up message/notification when my battery gets full due to charging or is there any software/package which can provide the functionality?

Comment: From what I noticed, the battery has a longer life if you always leave the note plugged, only unplug when it's really necessary

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Install the `acpi` package. Now put this in `return0whencharging.sh` and make it executable:

```
#!/bin/sh
acpi -V
if cat /proc/acpi/battery/BAT1/state | grep "charging state" | grep -vE ":[\t ]*charging$"; then
    exit 1
else
    exit 0
fi
```

If `echo -e "\a"` makes a sound, start this when you want to watch the battery status:

```
watch --beep return0whencharging.sh
```

If it doesn't make any sound or you want a notification and a better alarm than whatever watch can provide, install `libnotify-bin` and `mpv` and use this instead:

```
while return0whencharging.sh; do sleep 1; done; notify-send "Finished charging" && mpv -loop /usr/share/sounds/freedesktop/stereo/alarm-clock-elapsed.oga
```

**Explanation**:

If you look at the [man page for grep](http://linux.die.net/man/1/grep) you can see that `-v` reverses the matching, and therefore the return/status code. `-E` means it's a regular expression. the `[\t ]` in the regex (regular expression) means "tab or space". The following star makes it mean "tab or space 0 or more times". The trailing "$" means that it should match the end of the line. The final `grep` means that lines NOT ending in a ":", any number of tabs or spaces and then "charging" and the end of the line should make `grep` exit with status code 0. This means that `grep` will return 1 as long as the computer is charging. The `if` will execute it's first branch when the status code is 0, which means we are effectively negating the result of `grep`, since we `exit 1` when grep exits 0 and `exit 0` when grep exists non-zero.

Comment: if you want these commands explained, just ask me

Comment: i m not sure what this grep -vE ":[\t ]*charging$" will do. Could you please explain the commands.  thanks

Comment: added explanation

Comment: And where is this `return0whencharging.sh` file? Or if I create it, is there a specific place I have to save it?

Comment: @AvatarParto: doesn't matter where. name doesn't matter either, as long as you change it everywhere

Answer (score 9):

I have written a small script that will do that:

[image: screenshot]

---

**Script:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
while true
do
    export DISPLAY=:0.0
    battery_percent=$(acpi -b | grep -P -o '[0-9]+(?=%)')
    if on_ac_power; then
        if [ "$battery_percent" -gt 95 ]; then
            notify-send -i "$PWD/batteryfull.png" "Battery full." "Level: ${battery_percent}% "
        fi
    fi
    sleep 300 # (5 minutes)
done
```

---

**Installation:**

Run:

```
sudo apt-get install acpi
git clone https://github.com/hg8/battery-full-notification.git
cd battery-full-notification/
chmod +x batteryfull.sh
```

Copy the script to `~/bin` folder ([why the ~/bin folder?](https://superuser.com/questions/185184/where-should-i-put-my-script)) :

```
cp batteryfull.* ~/bin
```

Or copy it to `/usr/local/bin` if you want it to be available for all users on your computer:

```
cp batteryfull.* /usr/local/bin
```

Then add `batteryfull.sh` script as a startup application by:

- Open Dash
- Search for **Startup Applications**
- Double-click the icon
- Click <kbd>Add</kbd> and fill in as follows:

  [image: startup application batteryfull]

Answer (score 2):

Here is the Crontab that I use

1. Notify if battery is **full** (equal to 100%)

   ```
   */1 * * * * if [ $(cat /sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/capacity) -eq 100 ]; then XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/$(id -u) notify-send Hey "Battery Full"; fi
   ```
2. Notify if battery is **low** (less than or equal to 10%)

   ```
   */1 * * * * if [ $(cat /sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/capacity) -le 10 ]; then XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/$(id -u) notify-send Hey "Battery Low"; fi
   ```

Example Notification Image:

[image: Example Notification Image]

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the same thing and found [this](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1466/full-battery-indicator/) extension and it works as expected.